# Is it possible to use an angular-fontawesome icon in sweetalert2 title?

Tags: sweetalert2, angular-fontawesome

Is it possible to use an angular-fontawesome icon inside a sweetalert2 title?
I tried this but it doesn't work, the icon doesn't show and the inspector show size 0x0. I tried overriding the styles but I'm not very good with CSS.

```
swal.fire({
       title:  "<fa-icon [icon]="faBug" [border]="true" size="6x"></fa-icon>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/guide/advanced-uses.md#include-icon-in-the-markup-passed-as-a-string-to-a-javascript-library) to learn how to pass icon to an arbitrary JavaScript library and why what you have attempted to do does not work.

Below is an example from there:

```js
import { icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faChevronLeft, faChevronRight } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

myTooltipLib({
    content: `<p><b>Hint:</b> You can navigate items with ${icon(faChevronLeft).html.join('')} and ${icon(faChevronRight).html.join('')} buttons.</p>`
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I completely overlooked that section in the documentation, and had to read it 
 twice to understand how it works. It's embarrassing how simple it is.